# print and match rows where two columns match between two files

Tags: unix, awk, match

I want to match column 1 and 2 from the file for_matching with files in different directories in the path and named */*.file and print the entire row that matches those columns

*/*.file (example)

```
carrot 124555 1 2 6
hair 9922 2 2 2
tree 2223 2 1 2
```

for_matching

```
carrot 124555
```

output

```
carrot 124555 1 2 6
```

Right now I can just match column 1 between the two.

```
for i in */*.file; do awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next}; $1 in a {print a[$1]}' $i for_matching > $i.matched; done
```

Comment: PLEASE use globs, not `ls` for a loop over files : `for i in */*.file` and stop using backticks in 2018, prefer `$( )`

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1,$2];next}(($1,$2) in arr)' for_matching file
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat file
carrot 124555 1 2 6
hair 9922 2 2 2
tree 2223 2 1 2

$ cat for_matching 
carrot 124555

$ awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1,$2];next}(($1,$2) in arr)' for_matching file
carrot 124555 1 2 6
```

Same with multiple files, no need of `ls */*.file`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in */*.file; do
    awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1,$2];next}(($1,$2) in arr)' for_matching "$i" >"$i.matched"
done
```

Comment: you don't need a for loop, `awk` can read multiple files  `awk ... formatching *.file`.  Will save you from running multiple `awk` processes....

Comment: @karakfa yes, but from OP post it looks like OP wants to save matched records in individual file

Comment: there is `print > FILENAME".matched"` for that.

Comment: @karakfa yes possible.

Comment: is there anyway to also print the unmatched line from the file for_matching ? Or a blank line?

Answer (score 1):

That is so simple that you could just:

```
$ grep -F -w -f for_matching file
carrot 124555 1 2 6
```

For a limitation see @karakfa's comment below.

<s>That could of course be circumvented with (:</s>

```
$ cat file
carrot 124555 1 2 6
1 carrot 124555 1 2 6

$ grep -w -f <(sed 's/^/^/g' for_matching) file
carrot 124555 1 2 6
```

Comment: this will match if the same pair appears on fields `2-`

Comment: This is one of those answers that's dangerous because it looks simple and will produce the expected output from some specific sample input but then will quietly bite you in the ass later given different input when you're counting on it.

Comment: @EdMorton which is why I think I should stick to the awk answer - my files are 13Million lines long and I have 500 of them so will compare outputs between this and the awk answer!

Comment: Just be aware that bulk input is no substitute for considered input. Your 13 Million lines might not have any problems but that doesn't mean there are no problems or that your next 10 lines might bomb. Really **think** about what this code is doing and you'll be able to come up with test cases that cause it to fail. For example, try this and the awk solution if `for_matching` just contained the word `carrot` alone or started with `car.ot` instead of `carrot`, or....

Comment: @EdMorton You are right, of course. The latter part was just a joke (hence the smiley :) and @karakfa's comment still stands stands. And thanks for the heads up on `.`, I forgot to add `-F`.